# No se muestra la salida por DBMS en Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Por algún motivo al ejecutar el siguiente código no se muestra el resultado de la consulta por la salida de dbms. Se ha probado el mismo código en otro PC y funciona. Por la salida de script muestra que todo ha ido bien:

> Procedimiento PL/SQL terminado correctamente.

```
BEGIN
For x IN(SELECT SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME FROM MTL_SECONDARY_INVENTORIES WHERE ORGANIZATION_ID=203)LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

No tengo más información para explicar esto. ¿Qué puedo estar pasando y no deja que salga el resultado por la salida DBMS?

Comment: has ejecutado antes `set serveroutput on;` ???

Comment: Si, pero no funciona. Como ya he comentado, ese código funciona bien en otro PC.

Comment: Que sistemas operativos tiene cada uno?? En window10 yo he tenido algún qe otro problema con el sql dev

Comment: Ambos tienen Windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

Para poder ver la salida de `DBMS_OUTPUT` en SQL Developer, debes seguir las 2 etapas siguientes:

1. Abrir la ventana **Dbms Output**.

   Esto lo haces desde el menú: **View --> Dbms Output**.
2. Activar `DBMS_OUTPUT` para la conexión a la base de datos.

   Para esto, pulsa el icono **+**, selecciona la conexión adecuada y pulsa **OK**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo debería funcionar correctamente ahora.

Comment: Eso ya lo hice, pero nada.

Comment: Para asegurarte que no es un problema de datos, has probado un ensayo bien simple como: `begin dbms_output.put_line('hola'); end;`?

Comment: Lo más básico no funciona.

Comment: Buen día. Ya he intentado hacer lo que mencionan pero ni aun asi me muestra el resultado, solamente me sale Procedimiento PL/SQL terminado correctamente. y nada mas ¿algún tip?

Answer (score 3):

Si estás llamando al procedimiento desde una terminal (espero qué si), prueba:

```
set serveroutput on;
```

O en el script, al principio, lo escribes para que se active directamente.

```
set serveroutput on

BEGIN
For x IN(SELECT SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME FROM MTL_SECONDARY_INVENTORIES WHERE ORGANIZATION_ID=203)LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Acto seguido, llama/ejecuta de nuevo al procedimiento y ya debería aparecerte la salida del dbms_ouput.